# HQL count from multiple tables

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql

I would like to query my database using a HQL query to retrieve the total number of rows having a `MY_DATE` greater than `SOME_DATE`.

So far, I have come up with a native Oracle query to get that result, but I am stuck when writing in HQL:

```
SELECT
    (
     SELECT COUNT(MY_DATE) 
     FROM Table1 
     WHERE MY_DATE >= TO_DATE('2011-09-07','yyyy-MM-dd') 
    ) 
    + 
    (
     SELECT COUNT(MY_DATE) 
     FROM Table2 
     WHERE MY_DATE >= TO_DATE('2011-09-07','yyyy-MM-dd')
    ) 
AS total
```

I actually have more than 2 tables but I keep having an `IllegalArgumentException` (`unexpected end of subtree`).

The working native Oracle basically ends with `FROM dual`.

What HQL query should I use to get the total number of rows I want?

Answer (score 1):

First of, if you have a working SQL query, why not just use that instead of trying to translate it to HQL? Since you're returning a single scalar in the first place, it's not like you need anything HQL provides (e.g. dependent entities, etc...)

Secondly, do you have 'dual' mapped in Hibernate? :-) If not, how exactly are you planning on translating that?

That said, "unexpected end of subtree" error is usually caused by idiosyncrasies of Hibernate's AST parser. A commonly used workaround is to prefix the expression with '0 +':

```
select 0 + (
   ... nested select #1 ... 
       ) + (
   ... nested select #2 ... 
       ) as total
  from <from what exactly?>
```